# Can you please check if this query will avoid concurrent update

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm creating a Queuing system, with mysql and vb.net that prints ticket no.

Scenario:
Ticket will proceed to billing (2 windows), then after that proceed to cashier (2 windows) when ticket is called on dashboard, then after cashier  - ticket will be closed.

My tbl_ticket

[image: tbl_ticket]

I have here my MySql query that assign a ticket to a cashier window. this works for a single cashier user. but I have 2 cashier.

Cashier 1 = (@agentID = 1) and Cashier 2 = (@agentID = 2)

```
UPDATE tbl_ticket, (
SELECT * FROM tbl_ticket WHERE current_agent = 0 AND cashier_stat = 1 AND DATE(tag_time) = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY tag_time ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
) as ticket 
SET tbl_ticket.current_agent = @agentID
WHERE tbl_ticket.id = ticket.id;
```

I update tbl_ticket with agentid on tbl_ticket.current_agent for assigning what ticket to assess for Cashier 1 or Cashier 2.

Does this query can ensure that if two cashier execute this in the same time they will not be assigned in the same number in sequence? I want 2 cashier to get different ticket at the same time.

Comment: I think I'd be tempted to use a transaction

Comment: Can you give example, enlighten me please @Strawberry